# Exuberant Ctags - Duplicate tags problem

Tags: ctags

Here is a file -- `ChipBooter.cpp` -- in my project(Omit some details that are not related to this question):

```
class ChipBooter {
public:   
    void Boot() {
        this->DpDetect();
    }
    void DpDetect() {}
}
```

When I hit `g<C-]>` to jump to the definition of `DpDetect`, Vim displayed a list with duplicate matching tags:

```
# pri kind tag               file
1 F C f    DpDetect          OMU/src/boot/src/ChipBooter.cpp
             class:ChipBooter
             void ChipBooter::DpDetect()
2 F C f    DpDetect          OMU/src/boot/src/ChipBooter.cpp
             class:ChipBooter
             void ChipBooter::DpDetect()
```

This is the same definition!

This problem happens every time I hit `g<C-]>` and always doubles the length of the list.

---

**More Details**

Exuberant Ctags version: `5.8`. Vim version is `7.3`

Here is a visual representation of my directory hierarchy:

```
Source
  `---tags
  |       
  `---OMU
       `---src
            `---boot
                 `---src
                      `---ChipBooter.cpp
```

I ran `ctags -R` in `Source` which contains the `OMU` directory to generate the `tags` file.

I launch vim using `vim -u NONE -N`; `.vimrc` and plugins is disabled.

There is only one entry about `DpDetect` in the `tags` file:

```
DpDetect    OMU/src/boot/src/ChipBooter.cpp /^void ChipBooter::DpDetect()$/;"   f   class:ChipBooter
```

`tags` is default value, because `.vimrc` is disabled.

```
:set tags?
tags=./tags,./TAGS,tags,TAGS
```

---

**Update**

@romainl said Vim seems to be using both two *tags* files: `tags` and `TAGS`.

```
:echo tagfiles()
['tags', 'TAGS']
```

If I change `tags` option to exclude *TAGS* file(`:set tags=./tags,tags`), duplicate tags problem does not exist.

Where is the `TAGS` file? There is only a `tags` file in my project directory.

```
$ find {My project root directory} -iname tags
./tags
```

Comment: What is the output of `:echo tagfiles()`?

Comment: Vim seems to be using two tags files, `tags` and `TAGS`. Do you have a `TAGS` file in `/home/yufeng/mount/svncode/omu/zycp/Source/`? Could it be a case-sensitivity issue?

Comment: @romainl I think you're on to something. Given that every vim newcomer nowadays is working on Mac OS X, this might help the OP: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71357/how-to-check-if-my-hd-is-case-sensitive-or-not  I would guess that Vim is assuming that in Unix all filesystems are case sensitive.

Comment: @Vitor, I don't know much about Vim's guts but I can imagine it asking the file system for a `tags` file and then asking for a `TAGS` file. A case-sensitive FS would answer yes to both question, forcing Vim to search two times in the same file thinking there are two, while a case-insensitive FS would answer yes only to the first question.

Comment: Vitor's link tells you how for Mac OS X. Google will tell you for other OSes.

Comment: @romainl I mounted my project file in Windows to Fedora. But Mount is case-insensitive though Fedora is case-sensitive. It seems that it is the *mount* that led this problem. see: http://superuser.com/questions/680492/mounts-arent-case-sensitive

Comment: BTW, I mixed up case-sensitive and case-insensitive in my previous comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @romainl said, It is indeed an FS(file system) case-sensitivity issue.

My project file is mounted from Window 7 to my Fedora using:

```
mount {Windows 7 Dir} {Fedora Dir} /local_folder -t cifs -o username=xxxx,password=xxxx
```

From the [mount.cifs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) man page:

> case sensitive is the default if the server supports it.

It means that the Mount will preserve the case-sensitivity of the server FS. If the server's FS is case-sensitive, these mounted files will be case-sensitive; If the server's FS is case-insensitive, they will be case-insensitive.

Windows 7 is case-insensitive, which makes these project files case-insensitive.

```
$ cd {My project root directory}
$ ls tags
tags
$ ls TAGS
TAGS
```

If 'tags' option includes both *tags* and *TAGS*:

```
:set tags=tags,TAGS
```

Vim will search the tags file twice: one for *tags*, another for *TAGS*. In both times, Vim finds that there is one fits. This makes Vim mistake one same *tags* file for two different files.

Consequently, Vim will use two tags files:

```
:echo tagfiles()
['tags', 'TAGS']
```

Thus, duplicate tags problem happened.

If 'tags' option includes only *tags*:

```
:set tags=tags
```

The problem will not exist.

Comment: BTW, why wouldn't Vim stop searching tags file when it has already found one? Thus, duplicate problem will not exist.

Comment: In terms of files, some people break their projects into multiple parts. For example, my main source might be tagged in one file and a shared library tagged in another, but I'd want to be able to find a definition either way. In terms of continuing once a symbol is found in the tags files, sometimes a project might have variants, where there are two functions of the same name but only one or the other gets built/linked for a given variant. When jumping to a definition like that, you'd want to be able to pick which variant you care about right now from the list, rather than only the first one v

Comment: (Continued) Vim finds.